# Assign foreign key object from kwargs in CreateAPIView

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a PartListing model that has a foreign key Org. I would like to have my post request automatically add the org to the listing based on the org in the url. I can't figure out how to set my save to give the Org object instead of either a QuerySet or just the org_id.

```
class Org(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class PartListing(BaseModel):
    org = models.ForeignKey(Org, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            related_name="part_listing")
```

My serializers:

```
class OrgSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Org
        fields = (
            'name'
        )

class PartListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    many = True
    org = OrgSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PartListing
        fields = (
            'org'
        )
```

My url patterns has this:

```
     path('org/<int:org_id>/listing', views.PartListingCreateView.as_view(),
         name='listing_add')
```

And lastly, I am trying to pull it all together here in my views:

```
class PartListingCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PartListingSerializer
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'org_id'

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        org_id = self.kwargs['org_id']
        org = Org.objects.filter(id=org_id)
        org_serializer = OrgSerializer(org, many=True)
        serializer.save(org=org_serializer)
```

This gives me an error of

```
Cannot assign "OrgSerializer(<QuerySet [<Org: Test Acme Corp>]>, many=True):
    uuid = UUIDField(read_only=True)
    name = CharField(max_length=200)
    primary_user = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_null=True, queryset=User.objects.all(), required=False)": "PartListing.org" must be a "Org" instance.
```

I have tried the following so far:

- Save 'org' - Same error
- Save 'org id' - Same error
- Added a Related Part Serializer to the ListingSerializer  (this didn't change the error)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Since the queryset is only one item by definition then I added org.first() in the save section.

```
        org_id = self.kwargs['org_id']
        org = Org.objects.filter(id=org_id)
        serializer.save(org=org.first())
```